# jsFiddle API to get row count of user's fiddles

Tags: jsfiddle

So, I had a nice thing going on a jsFiddle where I listed all my fiddles on one page:

[`jsfiddle.net/show`](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/13kqo9s6/show/)

*However*, they have been changing things slowly this year, and I've already had to make some changes to keep it running. The newest change is rather annoying. Of course, I like to see ALL my fiddles all at once, make it easier to just hit ctrl+f and find what I might be looking for, but they' made it hard to do now. Used to I could just set the `limit` to 99999, and see everything, but now it appears I can't go past how many i actually have (186 atm).

I tried using a `start` to `limit` solution, but when it got to last 10|50 (i tried like `start={x}&limit10` and `start={x}&limit50`) it would die. Namely because last pull had to be exact count. Example, I have 186, and use the `by 10's` solution, then it would die at `start=180&limit=10`.

I've search the API docs but can't seem to find a `row count` or anything of that manner. Anyone know of a good feasible solution that wont have me overloading there servers doing a constant single row check?

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same problem as you are. Then I checked the docs ([Displaying user’s fiddles - Result](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/api/fiddles.html#result)) and found out that if you include `callback=Api` parameter, an additional `overallResultSetCount` field is included in the JSON response. I checked your fiddles and currently you have [total of 229 public fiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/spyk3/demo/list.json?callback=Api&sort=framework&start=5&limit=5).

The solution I can think of will force you to only request twice. The first request's parameters doesn't matter as long as you have `callback=Api`. Then you send the second request in which your `limit` will be `overallResultSetCount` value.

**Edit:**

It's not in the documentation, however, I think the result set is limited to 200 entries only (hence your start/limit is from 0 - 199). I tried to query more than the 200 range but I get a [Error 500](http://jsfiddle.net/api/user/spyk3/demo/list.json?callback=Api&start=0&limit=200). I couldn't find another user whose fiddle count is more than 200 (most of the usernames I tested only have less than 100 fiddles like zalun, oskar, and rpflorence).

Based on this new observation, you can update your script like this:

1. I have tested that if the total fiddle count is less than 200,
   adding `start=0&limit=199` parameter will only return all the
   fiddles. Hence, you can add that parameter on your initial call.
2. Check if your total result set is more than 200. If yes, update your
   parameters to reflect the range for the remaining result set (in
   this case, `start=199&limit=229`) and add the new result set to your
   old result set. Else, show/print the result set you initially got from your first query.
3. Repeat steps 1 and 2, if your total count reaches 400, 600, etc (any
   multiple of 200).

Comment: finally got to play with this again. It was a near hit. Thanks for the suggestion. Only problem is, ?I have to subtract 30 for some reason. 229 isn't accurate?